# Trigger Event On PHP generated table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table where the content is being generated based on query results from a database.

Each of the rows have a status toggle button and a delete button along with other data relating to the query result.

What i would like to do is trigger an event on toggle or button click. I think i know how to do that however because each row is generated automatically i can't work out how to tell the toggle or button which fields i am referring to.

```
echo'<tr>';
echo'<td class="tg-031e"><center>'.$searchName.'</center></td>';
echo'<td class="tg-031e"><center>'.$searchCriteria.'</center></td>';
echo'<td class="tg-031e"><center>'.$creationDate.'</center></td>';

If($status=='Active'){
    echo'<td class="tg-031e"><input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive" data-  onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" ></td>';

}else{

    echo'<td class="tg-031e"><input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive" data-    onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"></td>';
}

echo'<td class="tg-031e"><center><button type="button" onclick="post();" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></center></td>';

echo'</tr>';
```

So if i were to toggle the switch or click the button how can I tell the code that i want the data on the row the button is on rather than any other row?

Many Thanks

Comment: add row id to button

Comment: Sorry to sound silly how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a unique id for the row to delete so you need something like this. I am assuming the the onclick="post()" is a javascript function that sends an ajax request to a script on the server, so just pass it a unique id.

```
echo '<td class="tg-031e"><center>';
echo '<button type="button" onclick="post(' . 
echo "'" .$rowId . "'" . ')" ';
echo 'class="btn btn-default">';
echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>';
echo '</button></center></td>';
```

Comment: hi guys sorry to add to here but apparently asking 3 questions is too many so i can't ask anything new.

Comment: if this is my code

    <script type= "text/javascript" >
    function sendForgotPassword(person) {
          $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'forgotpassword.php',
               data:{action:person},
               sucess:function(html) {
               }

          });
     }
     </script>
 


    <script type= "text/javascript" >
    function forgotPassword() {
        var person = prompt("Please enter your email", "info@legaleye.com");
     sendForgotPassword(person);
    }
    </script>

and everything in the php film works but the success does not trigger?